# How to Change 2 Onclick Button Tobe 1 Button

Tags: html, wordpress

Im working out with this Onclick Button

The Question is how to make that 2 button be 1 button

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" onClick="document.getElementsByClassName('player-embed')[0].style.width='70%';">
     Normal Views
</a>
<br>
<br>
<a class="btn btn-primary"  onClick="document.getElementsByClassName('player-embed')[0].style.width='100%';">
    Theater Views
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a function with the parameters you are demanding to change. such as the width.
then call that function from onClick.

Comment: Whats i mean here , can i change that 2 button be 1 button so when i click that 1 button its change to teather mode then when i click it again its will turn to normal mode

Comment: do you want a toggle button. try this out.
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch

Comment: Thanks ,its really usefull

Comment: @Beni Sugito: Dont forget to do a favor, who helped you!